# How to get a specific line from html code of a website

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude values of a user inputted city (in java)
I've found a website that offers this service (geonames.org) 
I want to extract only the lat and long from the html of the search.
For example, if I use the url 
||https://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=[CITYNAME]&country=||
, the coordinates are stored as such(by using inspect element): 
N 38° 53' 42''
W 77° 2' 10''
(lat and long of washington)
(url used - https://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=washington&country=)
How would I search for these specific lines, then extract the long and lat?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a sample response body for such a request. Please also include the Java code you have tried to parse it. Does it work?

Comment: Also, the site you mention offer web service access which might be easier to use. Take a look at [here](http://www.geonames.org/maps/addresses.html#geoCodeAddress)

Comment: What you're suggesting is called "Screen scraping" and while possible is ultimately extremely fragile, since any design change they make will break your program.  You could do it with Regex, or perhaps some DOM parseing, but you're far better off looking into the web service that bracco23 mentions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use their rest api instead of parsing HTML. 
Also make a note that for a city and country you will receive multiple records.

```
import com.squareup.okhttp.*;
import org.json.*;
public class GeoLookup {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://api.geonames.org/search?name_equals=San%20Jose&country=US&maxRows=10&username=demo&type=json")
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    String responseString = response.body().string();


    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseString);
    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("geonames");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("toponymName"));
        System.out.println(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("lat"));
        System.out.println(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("lng"));
    }
  }
 }
```

Here are the dependencies you would need:
okhttp-2.7.5.jar , okio-1.6.0.jar , org.json.jar